# I am trying to hide show menu from an <a><img> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show the `.list-menu` div show on click and then hide on click when the `.hamburger` anchor is clicked. Right now nothing is happening.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
        
        $(".list-menu").hide();
      
        $( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
        $( ".list-menu" ).show() {
      });
        
        $( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
        $( ".list-menu" ).hide() {
      });
        
    });
    });
```

```html
<div class="logo">
          <div class="about-me-button">
              <a href="#" class="hamburger"><img src="/img/menu.svg" alt="hamburger menu"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="list-menu">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function named [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that *"display or hide the matched elements"* and you need only 1 [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
   $(".list-menu").hide();

   $(".hamburger").click(function() {
      $(".list-menu").toggle();
   });
});
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  
  $(".list-menu").hide();

  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(".list-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo">
  <div class="about-me-button">
    <a href="#" class="hamburger">
      <img src="/img/menu.svg" alt="hamburger menu">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $(".list-menu").hide();

    $( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
      $( ".list-menu" ).toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be is the use jquery .toggle() method.

```
 $(".list-menu").hide();

    //toggle way
    $(".hamburger").click(function () {
        $(".list-menu").toggle();
    });
```

or if you would like to go an alternative route you can try something like this

```
//jquery alternative to toggle
    var toggle = false;
    $(".hamburger").click(function () {
        if (!toggle) {
            $(".list-menu").show();
            toggle = true
        } else {
            $(".list-menu").hide();
            toggle = false
        }
    });
```

I created a fiddle so that you can see how both would work.
https://jsfiddle.net/maenucze/